# Meaning of ID in "ID CARD"

Tags: british-english, abbreviations

What exactly does "ID" stand for? Is it an abbreviation of "identity document", or is it just the first two letters of the word "identity"? If it is an abbreviation of "identity document", shouldn't it be written "I.D." and not "ID", at least in British English? Meanwhile, if it is the first two letters of "identity", shouldn't it be written as "Id."?

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/id?q=ID, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/id, ...

Comment: I did, @None, and the dictionary said it is short for identification, but another source said it is short for identification document.

Answer (score 1):

"ID" is most often used as an abbreviation of "identity" or more often "identification". It is not usually short for "identification document" in my experience. It is therefore not normally used with periods. Indeed I don't recall seeing "I.D."

It may be that this use of "ID" came to the UK from the US, where initialism and acronyms without periods are much in fashion, and have been for many decades now. I cannot confirm that, however.

Comment: Funny enough my very old edition of the OED gives it as "I.D., identification, identity (card);" with periods. But **I** have never seen it written that way, so it might indeed have come from over there.

Answer (score 0):

**It is not unusual for abbreviations to "bend the rules"**

For example, "television" is abbreviated as "TV," and "infrared" is abbreviated as "IR." Presumably, someone just thought it made sense or sounded good, and the usage caught on.

ID does mean "identification."

Comment: Interesting. Television and infrared were however at one point made up of two separate words, so I can see why they are abbreviated like that. Identification is however one word.

Comment: Nobody ever said, or wrote, 'tele vision'.